# Do i need to bind/unbind the scroll event when i use scrollto jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto, unbind

I'm creating a horizontal scrolling site.Each time i click on the menu links i use scrollto to scroll to the selected section but when i scroll to a section using the scroll, not the links, it mess up the nav styling.
I think the problem is that i have code in the scroll event and scrollto its firing the scroll event too¿?

What i want to achieve is highlight the current link in the nav menu when:
1) i click on it
2) i manually scroll to a section with the browser scrollbar
3) i click next/prev links

Maybe the problem is in this part:

```
var position = Math.abs( $('#slider ul').offset().left - 138 );
$('p.status').html( 'index:' + getCurrentSectionIndex(position) );

//disable the scroll event so it doesn't broke the flow
$('#slider').unbind('scroll',handler);

//scrolls to the selected section
$('#slider').scrollTo($('#' + $(this).attr('class')), 800, { axis: 'x' });

//enable again the scroll event
//$('#slider').bind('scroll',handler);
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#slider').bind('scroll',handler);
}, 3000);
```

I'm new to jquery so if you see any thing that can be improved, please, tell me.Any advice is welcomed :)

I don't know if i've explained this well so this is the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/hvjbH/)

I'm using some of the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893124/use-jquery-to-change-a-class-dependent-on-scroll-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i did a 'simpler' version of your code, and it seems like it's working as you want.

[Click here to see the jsfiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3kka/)

Some of the update are:

A variable `index` recieves the index of the current item.

Acording to the `index`, the corresponding item os the nav will be highlighted using the `eq:()` selector, and I'm using this same method to scroll the page.

And im using the callback (`onAfter`) of the ScrollTo plug-in to bind the scroll event again:

```
$('#slider').scrollTo('ul li:eq(' + index + ')', 800, {
    axis: 'x',
    onAfter: function() {
        $('#slider').bind('scroll', handler);
    }
});
```

I am the disposition of any doubt!

Comment: yeah it works! so simple! i still have a problem, the link number 6 don't get highlighted and i don't know why.And this error makes the next/prev buttons fail.

Comment: @Oterox: The offset left of number 6 is not hitting the left of the scroll div, and that's why it isn't working as you expected.

Comment: but when i click in the menu nav link 6 the scrolls moves ok and the left offset of the panel #6 is hitting the left of the scroll div ¿?

Comment: then the problem is in the getCurrentSectionIndex function not returning the appropiate index because of the left position?